# My Express application returns error on response download

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get downlload response from NodeJs application. I need download some PDF file from NodeJs server.

```
res.download('C:/Users/pvalek.AD/Documents/repos/EasyOrder/Express/db.js', (error) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

But, in browser I always get Error response:

```
Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
```

[image]

I don't know why it's trying to parse PDF file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
let file=fs.createReadStream('<path to pdf>');
var stat = fs.statSync('<path to pdf>');
res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=quote.pdf');
file.pipe(res);
```

Comment: I don't want to download file from internet, I need to send it from my own server to the client end return as download response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
var fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
path = require("path");

app.get("/download", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let basepath = path.join(__dirname, "../");
    const file = `${basepath}/resources/videos/9d70a63cf6ffd7fc6c1581bb2a60b59.mkv`;
    res.download(file, function (error) {
      console.log("Error : ", error);
    }); // Set disposition and send it.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

`__dirname` is the router js file path (API path). and
`/resources/videos/9d70a63cf6ffd7fc6c1581bb2a60b59.mkv` is video file path the whole file path is a combination of these two paths. so when I combine them it's look like this.
`F:/Movies/resources/videos/9d70a63cf6ffd7fc6c1581bb2a60b59.mkv`.
this is the easiest way to download a file. you can use this code to solve your error.